# Programatically do a natural join on two tables

Tags: python

I have two tables (list of lists actually) that contain data and I want to do a natural join between the two programmatically (no SQL - just in code).

If I only want to join on a single common column at Index[0] in both can I do something like this:

```
for each row1 in table1:
   for each row2 in tabl2:
      if row1[0] == row2[0]:   // then this needs to join
         newRow = row1 + row2  // pseudo-code but essentially add the two rows together
```

First - does this make sense?

Second - is this a NATURAL JOIN (not 100% confident in the end result)

Third - is the a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it makes sense
2. Yes, this is a natural join if index[0] is the only common column. You should however create the `newRow` like below, so the index is not repeated within the row:

   ```
   newRow = row1 + row2[1:]
   ```
3. The current time complexity is O(n^2). You can do this in O(n) time complexity, if you use a hash, though in this case there is an added space complexity of O(n) for the hash

   ```
   hash = {}
   for idx, row1 in enumerate(table1):
       hash[row1[0]] = idx #save the index of row by the key value

   for row2 in table2:
       if hash.has_key(row2[0])
            newRow = table1[hash[row2[0]]] + row2[1:]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `astropy` library to manipulate the tables. You read two table and then use `hstack` to join two table with the same number of rows together.

```
from astropy.table import Table, hstack
from astropy.io import ascii
table1 = ascii.read("table1.dat")
table2 = ascii.read("table2.dat")  
print hstack([table1, table2], join_type='inner')
```

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed to use any internal libraries, needs to be done programmatically by me.